# cxGrid: how to cast a cell to a combobox-object

Tags: delphi, combobox, grid, tcxgrid

i have a problem with my cxgrid. in my cxgrid there a different rows and columns which have comboboxes as properties. but how can i cast a special cell value to a combobox-object? for example: i want to set the itemindex of the combobox in row 1 and column 2 to 0.

thanks!

Comment: you should tag this by language, environment, IDE, something.  combobox, grid, on what? Solaris? Windows? Mac?  cxGrid? You mean a developer express delphi component? THen use the tag DELPHI, PLEASE!

Answer (score 1):

The ItemIndex you cannot set, because it is suplied by the DataSource (or data provider).
But you can set other properties implementing the event OnGetProperties of your grid column:

```
TcxComboBoxProperties(Sender.Properties).DropDownRows := 9
```